# An application of the Delta method

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference

> I have the sample $Y_{i}\overset{i.i.d}{\sim} N(0,\sigma_{y}^{2})$ of a population with normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_{y}^{2}$ unknown. I could also prove that $\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}^{2}-\sigma_{y}^{2}\right)\overset{D}{\to}N(0,2\sigma^{4})$ using the CLT, but my question is:

> **Question:** How can I find a function $f(t)$ such that the variance of the limiting distribution does not depend on the parameter of interest $\sigma_{y}^{2}$ in the sense of the Delta method: $$\sqrt{n}\left(f\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{n}\right)-f(\mathbb{E}X_{i})\right)\overset{D}{\to} N(0,\sigma^{2}(\mu)f'(\mu)^{2}) , \quad Y_{i}\overset{i.i.d}{\sim}N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$$

For example, I could see that $f$ might satisfy $2(f'(\sigma^{2}))^{2}\sigma^{4}$ shouldn't depend on $\sigma^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such $f$ in general unless there's some specifics to your problem that I'm missing.

We need $\sigma^2 f'(\mu)^2$ to not depend on $\sigma^2$. To try to formalize this, I'll interpret "not depend" to mean
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma^2} [\sigma^2 f'(\mu)^2] = 0.
$$

In a typical Gaussian distribution $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are free to vary separately and neither is viewed as a function of the other, i.e. $\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \sigma^2} = 0$. Furthermore you write $f$ and $f'$ as only functions of $\mu$, and in general I think it'd be very artificial to have them depend on $\sigma$ since then $f$ isn't a statistic, so I'll also assume that $f$ and $f'$ do not have $\sigma$ in them.

This means the derivative is just
$$
f'(\mu)^2 = 0 \implies f'(\mu) = 0 \text{ everywhere}.
$$
But functions with $f'(\mu) = 0$ are excluded from the delta method by hypothesis so there are no valid functions that satisfy our requirements here.

Comment: the function $g(x)=\ln x$ it does not work?

Comment: @АлександрПальма are you interested in functions where there is some value of $\mu$ such that the result doesn't depend on $\sigma$? I was answering if there was a function where for any $\mu$ the answer won't depend on $\sigma$. If we're allowed to choose $\mu$ then any function with $\sigma^{-1}$ in the image of its derivative would work. E.g. if we do $g(x) = x^{5/3}$ then $g'(x)^2 = \frac{25}{9}x^{4/9}$ and if we choose $\mu = \left(\frac{9}{25\sigma^2}\right)^{9/4}$ then the result won't depend on $\sigma$. But i don't think it's very interesting if we can just choose $\mu$ like that